# Cloudinary intigration with azure mobile service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, cloudinary, cloud-integration

Hi I am trying to use cloudinary with azure mobile service, following from the link below:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/azure_integration

In the last line of the documentation it says I can access cloudinary in my backend script from environment variable. I am unable to access environment variable. Can someone please guide me how to use it.

Comment: Environment variables in Node.js are accessed using process.env.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language.  Node.js uses `process.env`, PHP uses `$_ENV` and Django (which is python) uses `os.environ`.    The docs for cloudinary are fairly straight forward, so you shouldn't have any problems.

If you are using Azure App Service (Mobile Apps), then you are likely using Node.js.

Comment: I am using Node.js, cloudinary docs are straight forward. I actually need help on Azure side. Do you know how to upload image form mobile app service using node.